# Identify a cookbook with a Deputy preparing a whole camel

Tags: identification-request

I recently came across this photo of an interesting recipe in preparing "Stuffed Camel"...

[image]

> Stuffed Camel
> 1 whole camel, medium size
> 1 whole lamb, large size
> 20 whole chickens, medium size
> 60 eggs
> 12 kilos rice
> 2 kilos pine nuts
> 2 kilos almonds
> 1 kilo pistachio nuts
> 110 gallons water
> 5 tbsps. black pepper
> Salt to taste
>
> Skin, trim, and clean the camel, lamb, and chickens, and boil until tender. (Be sure the pot is large enough.) Cook rice until fluffed. Fry nuts until brown, and mix with rice. Hard-boil the eggs and peel them. Stuff the chickens with eggs and rice. Stuff the lamb with 5 of the chickens and some rice. Stuff the camel with the lamb and more rice. Broil in large oven until brown. Spread the remaining mixed rice on a large tray and place the camel on top. Place the remaining stuffed chickens around the camel. Decorate rice with boiled eggs and nuts. And don't worry if there are more guests than expected - the recipe serves 80 to 100.
>
> Deputy Ruth E. Buntrock, FIC, Gaastra, Mich.

Now I am not here to debate if this is an actual dish or not. The practice of engastration [has been well documented](https://www.vice.com/en/article/7b7xyx/the-rti-sans-pareil-is-17-birds-stuffed-inside-each-other-and-it-is-delicious). In some digging the above recipe did [appear in a publication with some slight differences and credited to a different person.](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/stuffed-camel-recipe/)

> International Cuisine, presented by California Home Economics Teachers, 1983 (ISBN 0-89626-051-8) - Shararazod Eboli, Home Economist, Dammam, Saudi Arabia

[image]

Both these recipes appear to be poking fun at the practice as there are clear jokes in both citings.

**What I am interested in is the source of the first picture. Is there a cookbook out there compiled from law enforcement officers and this "Deputy Ruth E. Buntrock" was just having a little fun?**

Comment: Where did you come across the first photo?

Comment: Could come from [this thread on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/a67my5/recipe_my_friend_sent_me_when_i_asked_for/)?

Comment: @bobble I saw it on Facebook first, but it has been posted on many social media platforms as Gareth Rees mentions. It was even included in the Snopes link, but did not have reveal where their source was.

Comment: There was a real Ruth Elenora Fuleihan Buntrock who was b 1927 and d 2021 and lived in Gaastra, Iron Co., Michigan. https://www.ofieldfuneralhome.com/obituary/Ruth-Buntrock  She was a Civil Air Patrol Cadet her senior year of high school.

Comment: Also if you search "Stuffed Camel" in IA you will find multiple books with similar recipes.

Comment: Here's another reference to this meal. https://youtu.be/dIOOL2NiGZk?t=85 shows an unidentified printing of *The Usborne Children's Encyclopedia*, which says “The biggest meal [of the world] / [Roast?] camel stuffed with sheep, chickens, fish / and eggs is the largest meal in the world. It is / served at Bedouin weddings in Africa.” The video shows a newer edition, but I recall I've read this description in the Hungarian translation of that children's pop science book in the 1990s.

Answer (score 2):

The recipe comes from [I Served the King of England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Served_the_King_of_England) by [Bohumil Hrabal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohumil_Hrabal). The cookbook is a frame from the movie.

Comment: [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whole_stuffed_camel) also confirms it.

Comment: While this may be the origin of the recipe, that is not my question. I am looking for the book where it is attributed to Deputy Ruth E. Buntrock.

Comment: @Skooba The answer says (although a corroborating frame or video would be nice) that the cookbook in your post is from the film adaptation of *I Served the King of England*, which suggests it's nothing but a film prop and that's where the picture came from. So it does answer the question, although would be better with clearer evidence re the exact image.